# Where to change css code to adapt font-size and button sizes in buildfire app to customize styling as desired?

Tags: css, buildfire

I have a query concerning changing css for buidfire app.

In specific to adapt the css for the buildfire feature "free text questionnaire" in the marketplace.
Need to adapt font size (to be smaller), the col of the query text and the buttons for answering and next or previous to be smaller.

Can someone pls kindly help where to find the relevant CSS document?

I have already downloaded the sdk on GitHub.
But we don't need to develop a new plugin, only need the relevant CSS for the free text questionnaire feature to adapt those 3 things.

In one video "how to use custom widget" there you have directly the view to see those 3 possibilities for HTML view, CSS view and JavaScript in the control panel and next to it directly the results in the widget.

Where can get this custom widget?

If it´s not possible with this custom widget which css file is the relevant one in the sdk buildfire js plugin?? There are several css documents shown.
Which is relevant for customize font-size, button size??

Thank you very much for your kind help!

Kind regards,
Angelika

Answer (score 0):

I believe this the custom plugin you are looking for

https://github.com/BuildFire/customPlugin

However, not sure how would that help you since the free text questionnaire plugin is not an open source plugin so you cannot make changes to it and the custom plugin is just another plugin